# Keycloak ldap Server error triying to acces list of users imported

Tags: ldap, keycloak

I am trying this ldap Server and when I sync with the users of ldap all ok, but when I will go to list all of users imported, I get an error.

[import users ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMUsm.png)

[error listing users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRrOe.png)

[error trace 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdjJP.png)

[error trace 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf3fD.png)

I'm pretty lost as to what's going on and I can't understand why I can't list the users.

Comment: Looks like the connection to your LDAP server failed. Could this have been just a temporary issue?

Comment: After try to list of user, conection server faild

Comment: I got that, but is this reproducible? If you sync users again, does it still work?